# JQuery ignores .not() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have question, why JQuery ignores .not in this code:

```
$('body').not('#footer').on('click',function(){
    if (($('#footer')).is(":visible")) {
        $('#footer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Basicly, i want to close #footer, but only by click on other elements than #footer.
The code above does his job, but clicking on #footer also fadeOut this element, and this is not desired.

Ond on other side, this will work:

```
$('div').not('#footer').on('click',function(){
    if (($('#footer')).is(":visible")) {
        $('#footer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Now the downside is, that if i click on div inside #footer, this will also close it, so not perfect solution.

My question is, how i can target all elements to close #footer, but not #footer and his childern.

Thank You for advice.

I have used this selector :
$('body').children().not('#footer').on('click',function(){
This above, now closes #footer only when i click on body not #footer itself.

But now, clicking on element lef or right margin does nothing.
Screen to be more precisly, in image.[image]

Answer (score 9):

> why JQuery ignores .not in this code

Because your body element does not have the id footer but some of your div elements obviously do!

---

You could do this:

```
$('div:not(#footer)').on('click',function(){
    // if we're not a child of footer and footer is visible
    if ($(this).parents('#footer').length == 0 && ($('#footer')).is(":visible")) {
        $('#footer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

or a better solution is:

```
$('body').on('click',':not(#footer)',function(){
    // as above
});
```

As this does not bind an event to *every* non footer div on the page.

Or you can roll all the work into the delegate's selector to keep it concise.

```
$('body').on('click',':not(#footer,#footer>*)',function(){
    $("#footer").fadeOut();
});
```

Just keep in mind that with these delegate solutions, there is significant overhead since for every click on the page the handler will run, not just once, but once for the `event.target` and each of its `.parentNode`s.

So in each case, the selector will run and traverse up to the `body` to see if the element is in `#footer`.

This means that if you click a node nested 20 elements deep, it'll start on the `event.target`, traverse up those 20 nodes and see that it's not in the `#footer`. Then it'll start again on the `.parentNode` of the `event.target` and traverse up 19 nodes, then up 18, then 17 and so on.

Furthermore, the `.fadeOut()` will end up being called multiple times

So you can see that this is pretty inefficient overall.

---

Also keep in mind that these solutions require that `#footer` is a *direct child* of `body`. If there's some parent element before the `body`, it'll fade out.

Comment: *"Exactly how you have done..."* Well, no, it doesn't make any sense to keep the `.not("#footer")` there, it does nothing whatsoever.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, I misread the downside, and was updating as you posted. ta

Comment: FWIW, I'd lean toward `$("body").on("click", ":not(#footer)", ...)` (or `$(document)` to start, which is what I usually use for global handlers).

Comment: Yes, I think you have. Nice one. I only posted because you'd deleted, glad to see you were still working on it. You've got it covered. Feel free to grab anything you think is useful (which may be nothing) from that deleted answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but binding a handler to every `div` in the document except the `#footer` just isn't a good solution. Way more overhead than needed. Why not just bind a handler to `body` that hides it, and another to `#footer` that does `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @squint - I agree, which is why I added the example with binding to `body` - perhaps I should have been clearer that this is the better solution, but I was trying to keep it as close as possible to the OP's code

Comment: @Jamiec: FWIW, the `body` solution is probably closer to the OP's original attempt (top of the question). But as you say, both are there in your answer, so he/she can pick whichever suits.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the click function to all elements within `body` (except `#footer`) then replace -

```
$('body').not('#footer').on('click',function(){
```

With -

```
$('body').children().not('#footer').on('click',function(){
```

Comment: This works well, but ... Cant handle click, on some element margin. To be more precisly, if div has width 700px and margin 0 auto, it will be positioned, and then click on left or right margin, dont close footer ...